# free code camp -> Bonfire: Chunky Monkey

Tags: javascript, arrays

This Bonfire is from free code camp.

The task in this Bonfire is the following:

> Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a multidimensional array.

And my Code is the following:

```
var ars = [];
var all = [];
var ll = 0;

function chunk(arr, size) {
 for (var n = 0; n < arr.length/size; n++ ) {
  for(var l = 0; l < arr.length/(arr.length/size);l++) {
   if(ll < arr.length){
    ars[l]= arr[ll];
   }
   ll += 1;
  }
  all[n] = ars;
  ars = [];
 }
 return all;
}

chunk([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4);
```

This particular example for chunk returns

```
[0,1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

And this ist the same the checksystem thinks is correct:

```
[ [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5 ] ]
```

(I hope and think the spaces don't matter. Please tell me if this is not the case)

But it doesn't see this in what I am writing. It just sees

```
[ [], [] ]
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's javascript

Comment: Good grief, fifteen "answers", and not one of them even attempted to answer the question of why this code doesn't work; *every single one* is just another person's attempt at the original coding exercise!

Answer (score 2):

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
 var arr2 =[],
 i=0;
 while( i< arr.length){
  arr2.push(arr.slice(i,i+=size));
 }
 return arr2;
}
```

Comment: This is my solution for that bonfire. I hope it helps

Comment: You should explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces don't matter. I don't understand your question completely though. For what argument do you get the wrong data?

I think a huge problem in your code is that your function is manipulating variables in the global scope. Put those variable declarations for `ars` and `all` in the function scope.

This also works:

```js
function chunk(r, size) {
    var n = [];
    while(r.length) {
        n.push(r.splice(0, size));
    }
    return n;
}


var r = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<pre>" + chunk(r, 4).join("\n") + "</pre>";
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the answer I wrote. It is working.

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
 var up=[];
 var a=0;
 var b=0;
 while(a<arr.length){ 
   up[b]=[];
   for(var i=0;i<size&&a<arr.length;i++){
     up[b].push(arr[a]);
     console.log(arr[a]);
     a++;
   }
  b++;
 }
  return up;
}
chunk(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a slightly more clear version of @oumnya-benhassou 's answer:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var output = [];
  var count = 0;
  while (count < arr.length) {
    // while our count is less than array length, take the sub array by slicing
    var slice = arr.slice(count, count + size);
    // add this sub array to the output array
    output.push(slice);
    // increment count by size
    count += size;
  }

  return output;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    var holderArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + size) {
        holderArray.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
  }
  return holderArray;
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Couldn't figure out how to do it using just the slice method when I did it, but using the splice method should make it easier to understand.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
// Break it up.
var firstArray = arr;
var newArray = [];

//set loop condition to the length of the array, so it reduces by "size" every 
//time it loops and the .splice() method is called.

while (firstArray.length>0){       
  newArray.push(firstArray.slice(0,size));
  firstArray.splice(0, size);
 }

return newArray;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var times = Math.ceil(arr.length/size), start=0, tempArr=[];
  for(var i=0;i<times;i++){
    tempArr.push(arr.slice(start, start+size));
    start = start+size;
  }
  return tempArr;
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

Here:

- "times" variable represents the number of times the loop will get executed.

For example:
Consider this array (["a","b","c","d","e"], 2)
Here times = 3

In first loop, ["a", "b"]

In second loop,["c", "d"]

Third loop, ["e"]

Answer (score -2):

This is pretty clean

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
var placeholder = [];
for (i=0; i<arr.length;)
placeholder.push(arr.slice(i,i+=size));  


return placeholder;
}
```

First we create an empty array.
We create a for loop but without the i++ since we want to move in chunks.
We push the sliced array in the new empty array. slice(i+=size) works here
because the slice(x,y) starts at x and finishes at y-1 ( y is not included if you prefer ).

Answer (score -2):

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var i=0,j=size,pack=[],arrOutput=[];
  var loop=(arr.length/size);
  for(k=0;k<loop;k++){
    pack=arr.slice(i,j);
    arrOutput.push(pack);
    pack=[];
    i=j;
    j=i+size;

  }
  return arrOutput;
}
```

I use the dynamic pointer `i` and `j` to cut the original Array by `size`,and then `push` into the outputArray.

Answer (score -2):

```
    function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var newarr=[];
  var Len = Math.floor(arr.length/size);
  var len = arr.length;
  var num =len%size;
  if (num===0) {

  for (var i = 0; i < Len; i++) {
    newarr.push(arr.splice(0,size));
  }
  }
  else{
    for (var j = 0; j < Len; j++) {
    newarr.push(arr.splice(0,size));    
  }
  newarr.push(arr.splice(0,num));
  }
  return newarr;
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a two-dimensional array.

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var chunkArray = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i <= Math.floor(len / size); i++) {
    if (arr.length) chunkArray.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }
  return chunkArray;
}

console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4))
```

Answer (score -2):

I did it this way.   Hope it helps.

```
 function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var myArr = [];
  var loopCount = Math.ceil(arr.length/size);

  var pos = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < loopCount; i++){
    myArr.push(arr.slice(pos, size + pos));
    pos += size;
  }

  return myArr;
}

chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 3);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is another solution!

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var result = [];
  var s = 0; // Begin of the slice.

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // It goes like slice(0, 2+0), then slice(2, 2+2), slice(4, 4+2).
    // We increment s by 2 when we add to the array.
    var n = arr.slice(s, size+s);

    // Only add when slicing is not empty to prevent empty values.
    if (n.length !== 0) {
      result.push(n);
      s += size;  // Increment s by 2.
    }


  }
  return result;

}

chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3);
```